# Doing clustering with some data points always clustered together

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

Is there some R functions to perform clustering (hclust, kmeans, ect.) on `n` data points `X_1, X_2, ..., X_n`, with the constraint that some points `X_i, X_j, ..., X_k` are always clustered together? Or equivalently, is there some approach to perform clustering with given initial clusters `{X_i1, X_j1, ..., X_k1}, {X_i2, X_j2, ..., X_k2}, ...`

Comment: What do you mean by "variables are clustered together"?  Usually we want to cluster points, not features...

Comment: I changed the "variables" as "data points"

Comment: Why not just remove those points and run your clustering algorithm on the remainder?

Comment: All the data points are assigned to some initial clusters. These initial clusters are considered as meta-points and the clustering is performed on these meta-points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution: if using "hclust", set the "dist" values within the same initial cluster as 0, so that the points within each initial cluster will always be clustered together; if using the "kmeans", represent each initial cluster by a new point defined as the centroid of the cluster